# Does a protective sleeve become conduit if running between two junction boxes?

Tags: wiring

I'm wiring a few receptacles in my garage with cinder block walls. There is living space above, so I have to think about fire protection.

I'd like to run NM cable through the ceiling joists. (All wire will be 10/3 for maximum flexibility; I'd like to be able to convert all outlets to 240@30amps when required.) When I hit the walls, I'll need to wrap the wires in EMT to keep prying fingers away. I was thinking the most "beautiful" way of making the run is this:

1. Attach a metal junction box at the ceiling. I believe I can have a maximum size of 4x4 (16 square inches) per fire rules. The junction box would be attached to the joists and poke through the drywall.
2. To the junction box, I'd add a faceplate with a suitably-sized cutout for the EMT.
3. To the faceplate, I'd attach a stick of 4 or 5 foot EMT. The garage ceiling height is about 10 feet, and I'd like to get the receptacles at a low-enough level. The EMT would run down the cinder block wall ...
4. ...and be attached to a 4x4 box for receptacles.

I'd have the NM cable enter the junction box at the ceiling and then go down the EMT and into the receptacle box.

However, I'm concerned that doing this will convert the EMT from a "protective sleeve" into "conduit," and thus require more restrictive fill calculations. I read somewhere the EMT becomes conduit when it connects two boxes, but on the other hand, I don't know if that's the official definition.

On the other hand, if "conduit" is defined as connecting boxes, then I believe this plan would allow me to attach THHN to the NM in the upper junction box, perhaps making the conduit fill rules work out. However, that also seems more complicated than necessary when the system is just for protection.

So: **Does a protective sleeve become conduit if running between two junction boxes?**

Comment: If you're talking about **one** NM cable in conduit, the more permissive one-wire fill trades off with the gigantic fill size of NM cable being computed as round of the largest size of the oval and generally works anyway, so compute *that* before you get too worried about the definitions. #10 works against you but /3 works for you, as it's round, not oval.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. "Any thoughts" invites opinion which, I'm sure, you realize (you took the [tour], right?) is [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: I may be wrong, but can't you just poke your EMT through the ceiling (with an appropriate bushing on the end to protect the wire/cable against the sharp edge)?  Run the EMT down to your recep box.  If you use a box at the ceiling, your EMT will be offset from the wall.  Or am I misunderstanding your plan (likely because there are no pictures)?

Comment: Yes, just poking the conduit into the ceiling may be the better way...Thanks.